# Visual Composer (WordPress)

Tags: html, wordpress, веб-программирование, visual-composer

Здравствуйте! На работе повесили задачку (немного не по моему профилю) связанную с Visual Composer. Точнее, мне скинули html файл с индексной страницей нового сайта, сверстаной под Visual Composer для WordPress. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это интегрировать в composer? Есть ли какой-то механизм или как вообще уже готовый html для composera переносится на сайт. Полезных статей, к сожалению, не нашел. Буду рад любой полезной информации. Спасибо!

Comment: Насколько мне известно, нет никакого механизма переноса. Верстку под Visual Composer (VC) делают так, чтобы дать пользователю максимальные возможности для управления контентом. Блоки описывают средствами VC, все стили выносят в style.css.

Comment: А можно как-то уже готовую верстку VC, импортированную в html, вернуть обратно в композер? Спасибо

Comment: Не знаю таких способов. Верстал несколько раз сайты под VC, все руками.

Answer (score 0):

В visual composer есть блок raw html в него вы можете записать обычную html структуру. Но вообще не мешало бы пример глянуть

[image: HTML в блоке "RAW HTML" - front-end]

[image: HTML в блоке "RAW HTML" - back-end]

[image: HTML в блоке "RAW HTML" - front-end mobile]

Comment: Это полный треш будет, а не сайт. Адаптивности - конец, возможности редактирования сайта пользователем - конец.

Comment: Это понятно, но если учесть все выше сказанное, то по моему это единственный вариант, а в целом нужно смотреть пример верстки. А вот адаптивность причём? Если там подключён бутстрап, и в верстке классы бутстрап то оно вполне нормально будет работать

Comment: Единственный нормальный вариант - верстать руками. А по поводу адаптивности - ничего не будет работать, потому что у VC свои классы для строк и столбцов. Засунув все в один столбец с классами `wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html`, вы убьёте всю адаптивность bootstrap внутри этого столбца. Короче - попробуйте сами и убедитесь, что VC и bootsrap - вещи несовместимые.

Comment: Я тоже делал бы это руками, но сейчас речи идет не о Вас и не обо мне, автор спросил, цитирую "сверстаной под Visual Composer для WordPress". Тот кто верстал я надеюсь давал себе отчет в том, что он понимает, что делает. Bootstrap это был как пример, у VC есть свои стили, которые отвечают за разметку. Также в ответе я указал, что нужно смотреть пример верстки. Зачем мы это развиваем? Предложите лучше автору свой вариант решения задачи, исходя из того что он не работал с VC и скорее всего не особо разбирается в WP.

Comment: Добавил 2 скрина: первый с админки, второй - фронт.
Итог: `.vc_col-sm-4` нормально себя чувствует внутри `wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html`
Может мы просто не так поняли друг-друга :)

Comment: и как эта страница ведет себя на мобилке? где ее вживую посмотреть?

Comment: Это dev сервер - поэтому никак, скрин шириной экрана 426px - прикрепил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67701/discussion-between-eugene-v-and-kagg-design).

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся! Как было сказано выше - единственный способ выполнить данную задачу - "верстать руками". 2-3 дня мучений (обложившись доками) и задача решена.
Еще раз большое спасибо ;)